# Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, jsp

Estoy teniendo un problema con un método cuya función es devolver una lista de mensajes enviados por el usuario (suponiendo que el usuario es un atributo de la clase del método)

El código en cuestión es el siguiente:

```
private final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mensajeria";
private final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 

public List<Mensaje> verMensajesEnviados() {
    List<Mensaje> mensajes = new LinkedList<>();

    iniciarConexion();
    if (conexion != null && usuario != null) {
        try {
            try (Statement st = conexion.createStatement()) {
                String consulta =
                        "SELECT * FROM mensajes WHERE de='" + 
                            usuario.getEmail() + "'";
                try (ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(consulta)) {
                    while (res.next()) {
                        Usuario u = getMsgPara(res.getString("para"));
                        if (u != null) {
                            String texto = res.getString("texto");
                            Mensaje msg = new Mensaje(usuario, u);
                            msg.setCuerpo(texto);
                            mensajes.add(msg);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + 
                    ". >>> Error de Obtencion de Mensajes Enviados!!");
        } finally {
            finalizarConexion();
        }
    }
    return mensajes;
}

public Usuario getMsgPara(String email) {
    Usuario u = null;
    iniciarConexion();
    if (conexion != null) {
        try {
            try (Statement st = conexion.createStatement()) {
                String selectSQL =
                        "SELECT * FROM mensajes WHERE para='" + email + "'";
                try (ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(selectSQL)) {
                    if (res.next()) u = getUsuario(email);
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + 
                    ". >>> Error de Obtencion de Usuario!!");
        } finally {
            finalizarConexion();
        }
    }
    return u;
}

public Usuario getUsuario(String email) {
    Usuario u = null;
    iniciarConexion();
    if (conexion != null) {
        try {
            Statement st = conexion.createStatement();
            String selectSQL = 
                "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email='" + email + "'";
            ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(selectSQL);
            while (res.next()) {
                String nombre = res.getString("nombre");
                String apellidos = res.getString("apellidos");
                String pwd = res.getString("password");

                u = new Usuario(nombre, apellidos, email, pwd);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + 
                    ". >>> Error de Obtencion de Usuario!!");
        } finally {
            finalizarConexion();
        }
    }
    return u;
}

private void iniciarConexion() {
    if (conexion == null) {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + 
                    ". >>> Error de Conexion 1!!");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + 
                    ". >>> Error de Conexion 2!!");
        }
    }
}

private void finalizarConexion() {
    if (conexion != null) {
        try {
            conexion.close();
            conexion = null;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + 
                    ". >>> Error de Desconexion!!");
        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que me tira siempre la excepción

> ```
> Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed. >>> Error de Obtencion de Mensajes Enviados!!
> ```

Yo he estado revisando de arriba a abajo el código y no veo cual es el problema, he estado peinando internet buscando solucionar el problema pero no hay manera.

Comment: Al hacer el debug, en que línea te tira el código ?

Comment: El error debe estar en getUsuario, ¿puedes compartir ese método?

Comment: Sam: a mi no me aparece la linea donde tira el código, es la causa por la que lo he preguntado por aquí

Comment: ¿Y los de iniciar/finalizarConexión?

Comment: Ya los he incluido. También el driver y la URL de la Base de Datos (con dos tablas, una para usuarios y otra para mensajes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en que tienes un objeto Connection que reutilizas en los dos métodos getMsgPara y getUsuario.
En ambos lo inicializas y lo cierras, pero siempre sobre la misma instancia.

La secuencia sería:

1. getMsgPara: iniciarConexion()
2. getMsgPara: llamada a getUsuario
3. getUsuario:iniciarConexion()
4. getUsuario:finalizarConexion()
5. getMsgPara: trabajas con un objeto Connection ya cerrado, y da el error.

Lo más fácil que puedes hacer es eliminar la propiedad Connection conexion de la clase y que reutilizas y dejar el código así:

```
private Connection iniciarConexion() {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + 
                    ". >>> Error de Conexion 1!!");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + 
                    ". >>> Error de Conexion 2!!");
        }
}

private void finalizarConexion(Connection conexion) {
    if (conexion != null) {
        try {
            conexion.close();
            conexion = null;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + 
                    ". >>> Error de Desconexion!!");
        }
    }
}
public List<Mensaje> verMensajesEnviados() {
    List<Mensaje> mensajes = new LinkedList<>();

    Connection conexion = iniciarConexion();
    if (conexion != null && usuario != null) {
        try {
            try (Statement st = conexion.createStatement()) {
                String consulta =
                        "SELECT * FROM mensajes WHERE de='" + 
                            usuario.getEmail() + "'";
                try (ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(consulta)) {
                    while (res.next()) {
                        Usuario u = getMsgPara(res.getString("para"));
                        if (u != null) {
                            String texto = res.getString("texto");
                            Mensaje msg = new Mensaje(usuario, u);
                            msg.setCuerpo(texto);
                            mensajes.add(msg);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + 
                    ". >>> Error de Obtencion de Mensajes Enviados!!");
        } finally {
            finalizarConexion(conexion);
        }
    }
    return mensajes;
}
public Usuario getMsgPara(String email) {
    Usuario u = null;
    Connection conexion = iniciarConexion();
    if (conexion != null) {
        try {
            try (Statement st = conexion.createStatement()) {
                String selectSQL =
                        "SELECT * FROM mensajes WHERE para='" + email + "'";
                try (ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(selectSQL)) {
                    if (res.next()) u = getUsuario(email);
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + 
                    ". >>> Error de Obtencion de Usuario!!");
        } finally {
            finalizarConexion(conexion);
        }
    }
    return u;
}

public Usuario getUsuario(String email, Connection conexion) {
    Usuario u = null;
        try {
            Statement st = conexion.createStatement();
            String selectSQL = 
                "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email='" + email + "'";
            ResultSet res = st.executeQuery(selectSQL);
            while (res.next()) {
                String nombre = res.getString("nombre");
                String apellidos = res.getString("apellidos");
                String pwd = res.getString("password");

                u = new Usuario(nombre, apellidos, email, pwd);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + 
                    ". >>> Error de Obtencion de Usuario!!");
        } 
    }
    return u;
}
```

Comment: Genial! he resuelto el problema! Gracias por tu solucion

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser por que no estas cerrando correctamente la conexión, puede tener una instrucción en ejecución en un momento dado, la mejor opción es cerrar (**st.close()**) la primera sentencia y ejecutar la segunda.